# Does installing VSTO addin with ClickOnce edit the registry?

Tags: excel, visual-studio-2013, registry, vsto, clickonce

I currently have a VSTO Excel addin which is installed via Installshield but was looking at using the ClickOnce installer (on the publishing tab) instead.

I've tested building it through ClickOnce and it does load in Excel. I'm slightly confused however as I have not specified the registry keys in order for excel to load the add in.

Is ClickOnce editing the registry or is it using a different mechanism to load the addin?
Secondly, does installing an add in via ClickOnce require admin privileges?

Comment: There are 5 different ways to install an Excel Add-in: http://www.bettersolutions.com/excel/ECA723/LD023821888.htm

Comment: I'd have to look up the exact registry keys but I definitly know that ClickOnce will create some under HKCU. It pulls the necessary values from the ClickOnce manifest. Also I cannot confirm 100% sure but I think Standard User privileges are sufficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No ClickOnce does not require admin rights.  HOWEVER, if you specify a dependency in your setup program such as .NET framework or Visual Studio Tools for Office, then the ClickOnce program WILL prompt for admin credentials to install those prerequisite components if they are not already installed.  Also, if you need to install for all users on the computer, then I'm pretty sure ClickOnce won't be able to do that since installing for all users requires writing the HKLM registry, which is a privileged operation.

Comment: Any clue on know how it registers the plugin without editing the registry?

Comment: My guess is ClickOnce probably does modify the registry, just not under the HKLM hive since that would require admin rights.  If you want to be sure exactly what happens to the registry when you use ClickOnce, then you should download Process Monitor http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645